# Ajax not working in only android google-chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML CODE :

```
<form id="form" style="border: 2px solid white; padding: 20px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Registration Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="regno" placeholder="Registration Number" name="regno" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneno" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <button  class="btn btn-primary sub_btn" id="submit" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue;">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
```

My Javascript/Jquery code:

```
    $('#form').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var phoneno = $('#phone').val();
if(phoneno.length > 12 || phoneno.length <10){
    swal("Enter a valid phone no!!");
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    return false;
}
var regno = $('#regno').val();
var patt = /^([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{3,4})$/;
if(!patt.test(regno))
{
    swal("Enter a valid registration number");
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    return false;
}


var name = $('#username').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
if(name.length==0 || email.length==0){
    swal("Enter all fields");
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    return false;
}
var data = {
        'name'   : $('#username').val(),
        'email'  : $('#email').val(),
        'phoneno': $('#phone').val(),
        'regno'  : $('#regno').val()
};
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://reversecodingsubs.herokuapp.com/subs",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json", 
    encode: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.sub_btn').text('subscribing...');
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    swal("Great job!", "You are successfully registered!", "success")
    $('.sub_btn').text('subscribe');
    $('#form')[0].reset();
});
return true;
```

});

Everything is working fine in all other PC browsers and mobile browsers, except google chrome in android? What exactly is causing the problem in android chrome?
I tried without cache: false, but didn't work,
I tried putting method and action attribute on form, then also in mobile chrome, it didn't work.
I tried all this after clearing cache and cookies of my browser, even then it didn't work.

Comment: What specifically “didn’t work”?

Comment: On clicking the button, nothing is happening, but in other browsers ajax is functioning properly.

Comment: can you debug and see where execution halts?

Comment: does the `console.log(data)` get called? try `<button type="submit" ... etc>`

Comment: The function is not at all gets called in android chrome, but again working fine elsewhere.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is working on my laptop and other's PC also, the only problem is on android google chrome, the page get refreshed on clicking.

Comment: @Brien I tried putting an alert at the beginning of function but it's not working.

Comment: @SauravBhagat does this behavior exist on Chrome browser in iOS?

Comment: No, it is working fine on chrome iOS.

Comment: have you tried type="submit" for the button, since submit isn't being called at all ... or change it to an `<input type="submit" ...`

Comment: If you connect your Android device by usb and navigate to `chrome://inspect` on your pc browser you can access the log, what errors does it have?

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried now, but again same problem.

Comment: @John Pavek, for your time, I checked the console and it showed that since my API request was using https, jquery CDN was blocked as it was called using HTTP.

Comment: Thanks @brien  for your valuable time.

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for your time.

Comment: If you have some time, add an answer detailing how you found the error so future readers can see the path

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem once I checked the console of my android google chrome browser, which showed me the error stating,

> you can't make a request over HTTP if another script inside it is being requested at https

(not similar statement though). And then it displayed :

> $ is not defined

and then I checked jquery CDN was being requested at HTTP and when I changed it to https, everything was working fine.